# Does indexing fields on select query improve speed

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a DB Query like following

```
select amount, date, denominations, user, time, branch from deposits;
```

Now i see my database started growing up 500k +. Now if i add indexes to these columns in select query will the select becomes faster ?

All help i see in internet says if the column is part of where filter then there will be performance improvement. My Question is does select query (without where) becomes faster because of indexing fields ?

Comment: I don't think so, but this is something you can easily test and measure yourself. The whole point of indexing is to provide a way to locate specific things that would otherwise require a search. Much like the index in a reference book: you can use it to jump straight to a topic. If you're just gonna read the book cover to cover, it provides no benefit, and takes up additional pages.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have a WHERE clause or JOIN clause, the query in question will do a full table scan. In some cases, myDBR can use an index-only query, but as you are fetching all rows, that would not help.

If you have 500k+ rows, ask yourself if you need all the rows. If you do, the result will be a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

"... does select query (without where) become faster because of indexing fields"

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:**  If you are fetching only a few of the columns *and* you have a composite index with *all* those columns, it *may* be faster.  This would be because that "covering" index would be smaller than the entire table.